# Why LocationManager is null after initialization? I'm trying to removeUpdates()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gps, locationmanager

I have a class "OldLocationService" (generally I'm using fused location from GoogleApiClient but I keep that class in case of old Google Play):

```
public class OldLocationService {
    static Location loc;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected LocationManager service;

    private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "New location: " + location.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

    };

    public void EnableGPS(String provider, Context ctx) {
        service = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(provider);
        if (enabled) {
            service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 0, mLocationListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS is not enabled");
        }
    }

    public void DisableGPS() {
        try {
            if (!(service==null)) {
                service.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "service is null");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Somewhere in another class I'm calling:

```
OldLocationService OLS = new OldLocationService();
OLS.EnableGPS(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mContext);
```

And I'm getting locations correctly. However, when I'm trying to disable GPS:

```
OldLocationService ols = new OldLocationService();
ols.DisableGPS();
```

Then in logcat I get:

> service is null

Why I can't remove GPS updates? How to do that?

Sorry for my English errors,

Defozo

Comment: You have to remove Location updates in your onPause() method of the Activity..

Comment: I'm using GPS in background in Service, so I'm confused. How removing Location updates in onPause() would help?

Comment: are you trying to remove location updates from a service ?

Comment: Yes, specifically from AsyncTask (onPostExecute) within Service.

Comment: Don't remove updates from AsynTask, check my answer.

Comment: And don't make separate objects for enabling and disabling Location updates, you must use one instance for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't make 2 instances of your `OldLocationService` class.. you must remove updates from the same instance from which you started them.. because each instance has its own copy of variables/fields, in your case `protected LocationManager service;`

```
OldLocationService ols = new OldLocationService(); // declare it globally


// in middle of some code
OLS.EnableGPS(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mContext);
 // more code here
```

If you're removing Location updates from a `Service` then you must put the code in it's `onDestroy()` method from the same instance:

```
public void onDestroy(){
    ols.DisableGPS();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```